# Adding a custom Hilt component

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

good day, i'm trying to create custom component in hilt so i followed this tutorial [medium](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/hilt-adding-components-to-the-hierarchy-96f207d6d92d) and this tutorial as well [documentation](https://dagger.dev/hilt/custom-components.html).
but when i run the application i get this error indicating that it failed to create the **viewholdermanager**
*kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewHolderManager has not been initialized.*
so i believe that i'm missing something as per my understanding "We use the provider Dagger generates for us to create instances of ViewHolderComponent( custom component)"
really appreciate your help. thanks in advance

here is what i done :-

```
@Scope
@MustBeDocumented
@Retention(value = AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class ViewHolderScope

@ViewHolderScope
@DefineComponent(parent = ApplicationComponent::class)
interface ViewHolderComponent{

    @DefineComponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun build(): ViewHolderComponent
        fun viewHolder(@BindsInstance viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?): ViewHolderComponent.Builder?
    }
}

@Singleton
class ViewHolderManager @Inject constructor(
    private val viewHolderComponentProvider: Provider<ViewHolderComponent.Builder>
) {

    var viewHolderComponent: ViewHolderComponent? = null
        private set


    fun setViewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        viewHolderComponent = viewHolderComponentProvider.get().viewHolder(viewHolder)?.build()
    }

}


@Module
@InstallIn(ViewHolderComponent::class)
class ViewHolderModule{

    @Provides
    @ViewHolderScope
    fun provideLifecycleRegistry(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): LifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(viewHolder)



    @Provides
    @ViewHolderScope
    fun provideArrayAdapter(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): ArrayAdapter<DataItem> = ArrayAdapter((viewHolder as BaseItemViewHolder<*, *>).parent.context, R.layout.item_dropdown_menu_popup,
        ArrayList())

}

class SavedCarItemViewHolder():  RecyclerView.ViewHolder(...){

    @EntryPoint
    @InstallIn(ViewHolderComponent::class)
    interface ViewHolderEntryPoint {
        fun getLifecycleRegistry(): LifecycleRegistry
        fun getDataItemArrayAdapter(): ArrayAdapter<DataItem>
    }



    protected fun onCreate() {
        injectDependencies()
    }

    lateinit var lifecycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry
    @Inject lateinit var viewHolderManager:ViewHolderManager
    fun injectDependencies() {
        val hiltEntryPoint = EntryPoints.get(viewHolderManager.viewHolderComponent, ViewHolderEntryPoint::class.java)
        lifecycleRegistry = hiltEntryPoint.getLifecycleRegistry()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your `class ViewHolderModule` to `object ViewHolderModule` otherwise `@Provides` is not executed. Please share your experience with this result and when it does not work, I will try to dig deeper in.

Comment: thank you for your time and effort but it gives the same exception in case of class or object

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Inject` annotation to constructor and inject ViewHolderManager